# "allocated" or "relocated" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, phrase-request

For the slogan of a company we would are considering something with the following meaning:

"European technology allocated in Africa"
"European technology relocated in Africa"

It is a European company that is opening a subsidiary in Africa. I am honestly not sure if either is correct. Maybe there is an alternative word to describe this meaning?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is about publicity and idiom but I suspect that you need to consider appropriateness, as both of your (unsuitable) slogans imply that European technology is superior and is going to a region where technology, if any, is inferior. It might be better to use a brand / trade name.: **X Factor expands into Africa** although this sounds more  like an announcement than a slogan. Slogans are about what you believe or strive for rather than expansion plans.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the two options you give sound particularly natural to my ear:

> European technology allocated in Africa

This suggests that you are distributing (or giving away) technology in Africa, which is (probably) not the case; you are a company engaging in commerce with the people of a continent, so you are not exactly 'giving away' technology. It also suggests that you are in possession of all European technology, which is (probably) not true.

> European technology relocated in Africa

This suggests that European technology was first somewhere else, but now is in Africa. Unless you are closing your non-African branches, this probably does not work.

If I may, I would also note that the structure of this slogan ('European technology' interacting with 'Africa') means you have to be very careful about the connotations of your slogan, especially in light of the history of colonialism. Be careful not to infantilize your customers. Many natural-sounding variants (e.g. "European technology given to Africa") may come off as patronizing. There is also the basic question: if you introduce a 'European technology' to your customers, and it is widely adopted in Africa, is it still a 'European technology'? Your company may make such a slogan obsolete quickly.

I might look in a different direction for a company slogan.

Comment: I would be thinking of those signs in South Africa and Rhodesia which read 'Europeans Only'.

Comment: There is not really any such thing as 'European technology' these days. Technology is world wide.